# clear combobox text entered in text box portion

Tags: vb.net

I created a simple program that reads and writes to an output file in the bin folder, it works almost perfect. btnRemove deletes the selected item in cboFriends(which is good).  However, I also need btnRemove to delete text entered in the text box portion.  How do i do this? I apologize in advance for the basicness of the question.

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter

    outFile = IO.File.CreateText("MyFriends.txt")

    For intIndex As Integer = 0 To cboFriends.Items.Count - 1
        outFile.WriteLine(cboFriends.Items(intIndex))
    Next intIndex

    outFile.Close()

End Sub
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strInfo As String

    If IO.File.Exists("MyFriends.txt") Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("MyFriends.txt")
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            strInfo = inFile.ReadLine
            cboFriends.Items.Add(strInfo)
        Loop
        inFile.Close()

    End If

End Sub
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If cboFriends.Items.Contains(cboFriends.Text) Then
    Else
        cboFriends.Items.Add(cboFriends.Text())
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    cboFriends.Items.Remove(cboFriends.Text)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What do you mean by _even if text is not “selected”_?

Comment: When I type it in its not highlighted.  This only deletes highlighted text.  That might be a better word to discribe it

Comment: and acually it looks like it only deletes selected items in list, even if i highlight my text in the textbox portion it doesnt delete it.

Comment: Well `cboFriends.Items.Remove(cboFriends.Text)` does the work for you. It removes the item you entered in the 'textbox portion' from the combobox isnt it?

Comment: cboFriends.Items.Remove(cboFriends.Text) Only removes the selected item from the list.  It does not remove any text i have entered into the text box portion.

Comment: for example i type "hello" then press [remove] it does not delete the text

Comment: after cboFriends.Items.Remove(cboFriends.Text) insert `cboFriends.Text = ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cboFriends.SelectedText would work if the text was selected, but if i type "asdfjkl;" and then press [Remove] it does nothing.
Upon further digging **cboFriends.Text = ""** does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking for the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

To set it to a blank string, do the following

```
cboFriends.SelectedText = ""
```